# Covariance of an RV with an affine transform of itself

Tags: probability, linear-transformations, expected-value, covariance

It is often mentioned that the requirements of a covariance matrix are that it must be symmetric PSD. 
We have a standard result $\text{Cov}[Ax, By] = A\text{Cov}[x, y]B^T$. In the context of the question this reduces to $A = I_{n_x \times n_x}$ and $B=KX+b$ where b can be neglected for the purposes of the covariance computation and so we get $\text{Cov}[x, Ax] = \Sigma^xK^T$ 
There is no guarantee that $\Sigma^x K^T$ will be symmetric (unlike $\Sigma^x$ or $\Sigma^y=K\Sigma^xK^T$) so how does this formula make sense intuitively if it doesn't fulfill the requirements of a covariance matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To paraphrase your question.

> $\mathsf {Cov}(x,Bx)=\Sigma^x B^\intercal$ .  Why is this not guaranteed to be symmetric, when that is a property of covariant matrices?

It is because that is *not* a Covariant Matrix, rather it is a **Joint** Covariance Matrix.  That is a different beast.

*Covariance Matrices* must be positive-definite symmetric square matrices by definition.

Being defined as the matrix of covariances among members of **a** random vector, they are the joint covariance matrix of a random vector *and itself*.

$\qquad{\Sigma^x {= \mathsf {Cov}(x,x)\\=\mathsf E(xx^\intercal)-\mathsf E(x)\mathsf E(x^\intercal)\\=\mathsf{Var}(x)}}$

The row-column element of this matrix is thus ${[{\Sigma}^x]}_{ij} = \mathsf {Cov}(x_i,x_j)$, while the transposed element is ${[{\Sigma}^x]}_{ji} = \mathsf {Cov}(x_j,x_i)$ , so these elements are certainly equal.

---

***Joint** Covariance Matrices* *need* not be symmetric square matrices; as they are the matrix of the covariances among members of **two** random vector.

$\qquad{\mathbf K_{xy}~{=\mathsf{Cov}(x,y)\\=\mathsf E(xy^\intercal)-\mathsf E(x)\mathsf E(y)^\intercal}\\\mathbf K_{yx}~{=\mathsf{Cov}(y,x)\\=\mathsf E(yx^\intercal)-\mathsf E(y)\mathsf E(x)^\intercal\\={\mathbf K_{xy}}^\intercal}}$

The row-column element of this matrix is thus ${[\mathbf K_{xy}]}_{ij}=\mathsf{Cov}(x_i,y_j)$ but the transposition is ${[\mathbf K_{xy}]}_{ji}=\mathsf{Cov}(x_j,y_i)$, so these elements *may* not be equal.

---

Comment: So even the PSD property wouldn't hold for the joint covariance matrix right? Consider Cov(x,x) = [a b; b d] with b=0 and $K^T$ = [p 0; 0 s] with p, s <0 then Cov(x,x) * $K^T$ = [ap 0; 0 ds] which must be negative semi-definite since a, d > 0 to begin with for Cov(x, x) to be a valid covariance matrix.

Comment: Indeed, that is so.  @Sharpfawkes